# ActionScript Syntax Errors

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, unreal-development-kit

I need some help solving some compile errors.

I was following a tutorial (at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E8oM808ETWs) and typed down all of the code displayed in the video. When I tried to publish, I was presented two compile errors:

> Scene=Scene 1, layer=action, frame=1, Line 16 '{' expected
>   Scene=Scene 1, layer=action, frame=1, Line 33 Syntax error.

Here is the code that I have

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface
import gfx.motion.Tween
_global.gfxExtentions = true;

var angle:Number;

function init()
{
    _root.Health._yrotation = 30;
    _root.Ammo._yrotation = 30;
    angle = 0;
}

init();

_root.onEnterFrame = function();
{
    angle +=0.1;
    var sined:Number = Math.sin(angle) + 2;
    sined /=2;

    _root.Health.Title._z = -200 * sined;
    _root.Health.Bar._z = -500 * sined;
    _root.Health.Value._z = -200 * sined;
    _root.Health.Background._z = 200 * sined;

    _root.Ammo.Title._z = -200 * sined;
    _root.Ammo.Bar._z = -500 * sined;
    _root.Ammo.Value._z = -200 * sined;
    _root.Ammo.Background._z = 200 * sined;

    _root.Weapon._z = -200 * sined;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_root.onEnterFrame = function(); // <-- lose this semi-colon
{
```

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I missed that. Thank you!

Comment: By the way, it's customary to mark an answer as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Scene=Scene 1, layer=Layer 1, frame=1, Line 3   ')' expected

attachMovie('basket','basket', 2, {_x: Stage.width-50, _y: Math.random()*(Stage.height:-150) +50});

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more on this answer and why it would help the author.